# angular http interpreta un error 500 statustext: ok y lo da por success

Tags: angular

Disculpad que solo pueda adjuntar una imagen, pero es que no debo sacar código de la empresa.

Estoy haciendo una llamada a la API interna de la aplicación, la cual por distintos motivos, está devolviendo un 500. Hasta ahí todo bien. El proble, es que el http de angular, está tomando ese error 500 como un success, con lo cual la aplicación que espera una respuesta, pues no puede continuar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es extraño porque todo el resto de error nos maneja bien, pero este error 500, lo interpreta por statusText ok con lo cual intenta trabajar con la respuesta.

No podemos, o no debemos hacer un check dentro de success, porque tenemos más de 2000 llamadas y sería poco efectivo.

Éste es el método:

```
registerSamples(list) {
    if (list && list.length > 0) {
      this.searcherService.registerSamples(list).pipe(
        finalize(() => this.isSpinner$.next(false))
      ).subscribe(res => {
        this.getParamsData();
        this.toast.success(this.translate.instant('Searcher_detail.SampleRegister_Ok'));
      }, () => {
        this.toast.error(this.translate.instant('Searcher_detail.SampleRegister_Error'));
      });
    } else {
      this.toast.error(this.translate.instant('Searcher_detail.SampleRegister_Error'));
    }
  }
```

Y este el servicio:

```
  registerSamples(list: string[]){
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/registre-entrada/multiple`;
    return this._http.post(url, list).pipe(catchError(error => of(error)));
  }
```

El pipe como decía el compañero, no es más que para volver a ocultar el spinner cuando llegue la respuesta.

---

Este es el método:

```
registerSamples(list) {
    if (list && list.length > 0) {
      this.searcherService.registerSamples(list).pipe(
        finalize(() => this.isSpinner$.next(false))
      ).subscribe(res => {
        this.getParamsData();
        this.toast.success(this.translate.instant('Searcher_detail.SampleRegister_Ok'));
      }, () => {
        this.toast.error(this.translate.instant('Searcher_detail.SampleRegister_Error'));
      });
    } else {
      this.toast.error(this.translate.instant('Searcher_detail.SampleRegister_Error'));
    }
  }
```

Y este el servicio:

```
  registerSamples(list: string[]){
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/registre-entrada/multiple`;
    return this._http.post(url, list).pipe(catchError(error => of(error)));
  }
```

El pipe como decía el compañero, no es más que para volver a ocultar el spinner cuando llegue la respuesta.

Me pasa con alguna respuesta 400 también

```
error:
error: "Bad Request"
message: "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `cat.gencat.ics.argos.siap.common.rest.model.BasicMostraTO` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `cat.gencat.ics.argos.siap.common.rest.model.BasicMostraTO` out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]"
path: "/argosd-siap-cas/api/mostres/cambiarTipusMostra/estudi/VH21B900004/mostra"
status: 400
timestamp: "2021-10-07T07:21:52.355+00:00"
[[Prototype]]: Object
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for http://backend-cas-svc-apa.apa-fra02-m3c-4x32-b739b21cfe2767561272bb0444567c74-0000.eu-de.containers.appdomain.cloud/argosd-siap-cas/api/mostres/cambiarTipusMostra/estudi/VH21B900004/mostra: 400 OK"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 400
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://backend-cas-svc-apa.apa-fra02-m3c-4x32-b739b21cfe2767561272bb0444567c74-0000.eu-de.containers.appdomain.cloud/argosd-siap-cas/api/mostres/cambiarTipusMostra/estudi/VH21B900004/mostra"
[[Prototype]]: HttpResponseBase
```

Comment: Falta el código: no pongas sólo imágenes (para mostrar el error pueden ayudar, pero el código ejecutado debería estar puesto como texto. Esa llamada a registerSamples, con un `pipe(finalize(...` no parece la clásica llamada AJAX trivial. Te recomiendo leer [ask]

Comment: No estoy escribiendo desde el mismo ordenador del trabajo porque está super capado a parte de trabajar por una VPN. Donde no puedo entrar ni siquiera aquí, pero bueno, eso es otro cantar.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el servicio está capturando el error y devolviendo el error como una respuesta "normal", lo que hace que no se pueda capturar más tarde, prueba a quitar `.pipe(catchError(error => of(error)))`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, quite la tubería y sigue igual. Ahora también me pasa en algún servicio con respuesta 400

Answer (score 0):

creo que el manejador de errores por defecto, no está funcionando bien, así que he picado un manejador personalizado y ha funcionado

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ErrorHandlingService {

  constructor(
    private router: Router) {
  }


  catchError<TRes>(err: any): Observable<TRes> {

    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      if (err.status === 500) {
        console.error('Error', err.status, err.url, err.statusText, err.error);
        return throwError(err);
      }
      if (err.status === 404) {
        console.warn('Error 404, resource not found!', err.url, err.statusText);
        return throwError(err);
      }
      //if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
      if (err.status === 401 ) {   
        console.warn('Error 401', err.url, err.statusText);
       // this.router.navigate(['/unauthorized']);
       this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return throwError(err);
      }

      if (err.status === 400 ) {   
        console.warn('Error 400 Bad Request', err.url, err.statusText);
        return throwError(err);
      }
      console.error('Unknown HttpErrorResponse', err);
      return throwError(err);
    }

    console.error('Observable error:', err);
    return throwError(err);
  }
}
```